# autoload functions in php

Tags: php, function

Is it possible to autoload functions?

What I have is I have written functions distributed over different files named after the function name, so what I need is to autoload the file containing the function automatically.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: See my solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352996/automatically-include-missing-functions

Comment: Related: [Autoloader for functions (19 Jan 2011)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737199/autoloader-for-functions)

Answer (score 5):

You can [autoload classes](http://php.net/language.oop5.autoload.php), so if you make your functions [static methods of classes](http://php.net/language.oop5.static.php) then it will work.

```
abstract class Util
{
    static function doSomething() {

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Util::doSomething();
```

Comment: Hi Piotr,
Yes, I know we can autoload the class, and what I'm looking for is some way to autoload the functions without using it inside a class.

It will be great if you can tell me how to do it.

Comment: Sorry I do not know if that is possible considering this would break any code optimization and bytecode caching.

Comment: sreejith, there is no way to do this without using Piotr Blasiak's recommendation, which is in fact a good recommendation. It will make your code a bit more usable as well. Right now, I am in the process of doing this for a large application. The result is going to be very well organized functions. (Each function will be categorized inside of a class, meaning all related functions will be a member of the same class. Making it more usable and easy to understand. It will also allow less includes when function calls are needed. This answer should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
include("path");
```

or

```
require_once("path");
```

References:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: Hi Evan,
I need to autoload the function dynamically like using the autoload() for classes.

Comment: @ Webnet, unfortunately I can't do that, I need the code placed inside a function and to include that particular file having same name as of the function automatically ( IF POSSIBLE)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, but you can load classes. using `__autoload($className)`

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not wise, it is possible.

You may save those functions in a file and prepend this file to all requested scripts:

- front controller pattern (one central file for all requests, include it there)
- php's [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

But the wise, OOP solution would be to group those functions into classes and use `__autoload` or some framework autoloader like `Zend_Autloader` to speed things up and load just the features you need.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. But you can add following code to top of your code to automatically include functions:

```
call_user_func(function($p,$w){$c=file_get_contents(__FILE__);$fs=explode('(',$c);$f=[];for($i=65;$i<=90;$i++){$vc[chr($i)]=1;$vc[chr($i+32)]=1;if($i<75)$vc[chr($i-17)]=1;}$vc['_']=1;foreach($fs as $fn){$fn=rtrim($fn);for($i=strlen($fn)-1;$i>=0;$i--){if(!isset($vc[$fn[$i]])){$f[]=substr($fn,$i+1);break;}}}foreach($f as $c){@include_once($p.$w[0].$c.$w[1]);}},
"func_dir/",["func_",".php"]);
```

The only thing you need to change is the second line: First parameter is the folder where to look for files, the second param is an array which wraps both values around the function name.

For example: If your function files are in the sub directory "func_dir/" and are namen "func_*.php" (where * is the function name), then you can use the above code directly as-is. However, you have to put that code in every file where you want to load functions automatically and adapt the path.

It's a little bit dirty, but it works. I hope my code helps you.

Comment: Sometimes, regexes are the answer (or, at least, are simpler than the non-regex implementation). `call_user_func(function($prefix,$suffix){preg_match_all('/(\w+)\(/', file_get_contents(__FILE__), $matches);foreach($matches[1] as $func){@include_once("{$prefix}{$func}{$suffix}");}}, 'func_dir/func_', '.php');` is equivalent, but just as inefficient. Also, there's no reason to minify sample code or PHP code.