# 'autoload' functions in php?

Tags: php

I have this problem that I have many huge functions, and I'm using only few in a given script.
Every function sits in its own file. It would be nice to be able to 'autoload' or rather require_once a file when given function doesn't exists.

Maybe is there a way to override `Fatal error:  Call to undefined function...` at the beginning of a script, so everytime that error fires up the script would first try to require_once a file name with name of a non existent function, and then try to call the function again.

Comment: Related: [Autoloader for functions (19 Jan 2011)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737199/autoloader-for-functions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since php [5.3.0](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.overloading.php) you could do someting like:

```
class Funcs
{
    public function __callStatic($name, $args) {
        if (!function_exists($name)) {
            require_once sprintf(
                'funcs/%s.func.php', // generate the correct path here
                $name
            );
        }

        if (function_exists($name)) {
            return call_user_func_array($name, $args);
        }
        else {
            // throw some error
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like (for example):

```
Funcs::helloworld();
```

Which would try to load a file in `funcs/helloworld.func.php` and execute `helloworld` after successfull loading.

This way you could ommit the repeated inline tests.

Comment: A great answer, just like the one I came up with for PHP <5.3 at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352996/automatically-include-missing-functions :) Wish I saw this earlier.

Answer (score 2):

[function_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php)

and the code may be like this

```
if ( !function_exists('SOME_FUNCTION')) {
     include(.....)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are scripting without OOP, you can use the **function exist** function:

```
if(!function_exists('YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME')){
    //include the file
    require_once('function.header.file.php');
}
```

//Now call the cuntion

//Reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

if you are using classes eg. OOP. than you can use the **__autoload** method:

```
function __autoload($YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS){
    include $YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS.'class.php';
}
```

//Now you can use classes you have NOT included in your current file.

//Reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 0):

[function_exists](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.function-exists.php) will do better

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try to write some error handling which includes function_exists, but the problem is determining when to load the function right?

Have you considered integrating your functions into classes so you can leverage http://uk.php.net/autoload?

Answer (score 0):

Undefined function errors are fatal errors for PHP. So there's no way to handle fatal errors (except hacks like [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)). It's better to think OOP way and use classes with [__autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Answer (score 0):

[function_exists](http://php.net/manual/function.function-exists.php) will not help you to catch the non-existing functions on the fly. Instead, you will have to surround all the function calls with if (!function_exists()). As far as I know, you can only catch non-existing calls on the fly with classes, using [_autoload](http://www.php.net/autoload) implementations. Maybe it would make sense to put your code into classes or put the related set of functions into one file and thus save a number of checks for function_exists required?