# Automatically include missing functions?

Tags: php, function, error-handling, include

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [autoload functions in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196881/autoload-functions-in-php)

I am working on a PHP framework. I wonder if there is a way to maybe rewrite the error handler when a function doesn't exist to automatically try to include the file stating the function first.

Example:

```
echo general_foo(); // <-- general_foo() is not yet stated.
                    // A handler tries to include_once('functions/general.php') based on the first word of the function name.
                    // If the function still doesn't exist - throw an error.
```

The win from this would be to skip compiling unnecessary files or to skip keeping track and state includes here and there.

Simply __autoload for functions rather than classes.

Comment: If it's a personal/internal framework, you could jerry rig something like f('fn', array([args])); but I don't think the trade-off is worth it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [autoload functions in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196881/autoload-functions-in-php) - err - [Autoloader for functions (19 Jan 2011)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737199/autoloader-for-functions)

Answer (score 2):

It does not exists and probably will never. Yes, I would like it too... However, this does not prevent you from using classes with static functions and let PHP autoload.

http://php.net/spl-autoload-register

Comment: So by calling a method rather than a function I would be able to accomplish something similar inside the class events?

Comment: Yes. I've added a link to the answer. But you should google for "PSR-0" and "PSR-0 Classloader" first (and because you are already googling: "Composer" ;)), so you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Solved by using __call(), see my posted solution.