# FuelPHP: Two questions - DB and Custom functions

Tags: php, pdo, fuelphp

I'm pretty new to FuelPHP.

My first question is what is the best place to put custom functions? Right now, I just made a new file, func.php, inside the app/classes folder and access it like `$func = new Func; $func->function_name();` - I don't think this is the best way to do it.

Secondly, for something I'm making, I'll be needing a lot of custom queries. Normally, I'd just use PDO's prepared statements and execute them, but I'm unsure how I'd go about sanitizing user input with DB::query(), without having to sanitize each individual variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autoloading function is not possible with PHP, so many people use classes, like you did... More information is available in this SO anwser: [Autoloader for functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737199/autoloader-for-functions)

For prepared statements, you got that: http://docs.fuelphp.com/classes/database/usage.html#binding

You still can use plain old PDO if you want, it's totally possible.

Comment: Oh dear, why didn't I just scroll down a little -.-
Thank you!