# Can I create a function in PHP that works as a system function (as echo,die, etc)

Tags: php, function

I'm always using a function to write to a log file, but this function is defined in a file among many other things that I don't need to include.

I was wondering, is it possible to define a function somewhere inside php to make it available without the need to include the source file? Sort of like how I can just use echo or die, or isset. Could I create my own function to use it this way?

Thank you.

Comment: Here is a nice answer to a question about autoloading functions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4737275/669073

Answer (score 4):

No. To do that, you'll have to write a PHP *extension* in C. Any PHP code will always need to be included explicitly one way or another.

PHP has the option to always automatically include a file at the beginning though: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you need to make a module with your function.
Other ways:

1. make autoload. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php
2. put only this function to other file and include it everytime you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can add you `log class` in `set_include_path` path  or add this function to `pear` library class