# how to use your own functions and/or classes in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, function, class, zend-framework

i have been creating my set of functions since i started coding and i want to use these functions throughout my project in Zend Framework 1.12
i know i can place in a folder that i would create in the library, however i am looking for a different way to use my functions.
if i placed my functions in:

```
.../library/myfunctionsfolder/myfunctions.php
```

i would have to include this file in every controller when i need to use any function from this file.
However i am looking for a way that i can directly call a function from the file in any controller without having to include the file.
 For example:

```
my_function($some_var);
```

Should i include this file in Zend_Controller or is it a bad idea?
How Can i do that?
Thanks for any help

Comment: this answer is true for ZF1, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737199/autoloader-for-functions?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: step2 (preloading) you could do in the Bootstrap.php.

Comment: @redreggae How could i use preloading, can you post an example?
Would it enable me to use the functions as i described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said the following points are all valid for ZF1: [Autoloader for functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737199/autoloader-for-functions?answertab=votes#tab-top)

If you really like to use functions and want to preload them then the best place for doing so is the Bootstrap.php.

So in the `Application\Bootstrap.php` just create a new method with prefix `_init`:

```
protected function _initPreloading()
{
    include LIBRARY_PATH."/myfunctionsfolder/myfunctions.php";
    include LIBRARY_PATH."/myfunctionsfolder/myfunctions2.php";
}
/* For those who does not know how to address the library (in case you cannot use LIBRARY_PATH) You can use this:
include ( APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/Customfunctions/functions.php'); */
```

For this to work you need the following 2 lines in your application.ini:

```
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
```

**UPDATE:**

To use `LIBRARY_PATH` I've included the following into index.php:

```
// Define path to library directory
defined('LIBRARY_PATH') 
    || define('LIBRARY_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../library'));
```

More info on Bootstrapping: [Bootstrapping](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.theory-of-operation.html#zend.application.theory-of-operation.bootstrap)

Another way would be to use a controller plugin for conditional preloading. If you only need certain functions in a controller.

More info on how to write a plugin: [Plugins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html)

Comment: How would i call the function from the file when it is like this?

Comment: Just call it ;) You can call a function from everywhere if the file is included..

Comment: And if you include the file in the Bootstrap.php it's available anywhere

Comment: woo hoo :) i was having trouble addressing the library folder. now wherever i call the function it is working.
thanks alot