# Autoload classes and functions from different files and directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, class, include, autoload

I have this autoload code :

```
function __autoload($class_name)
{
    //class directories
    $directorys = array(
        './Controls/',
        './Config/',
        './Utility/'
    );
    //for each directory
    foreach($directorys as $directory)
    {
        //see if the file exsists
        if(file_exists($directory.$class_name . '.php'))
        {
            require_once($directory.$class_name . '.php');
            //only require the class once, so quit after to save effort (if you got more, then name them something else
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I have three directories that they're holding all of my classes and functions.

Can I create a single autoload file in `Controls` directory and use it to load all function or classes in other php files I mean for example `index.php` file in `/portal/main/index.php`

is it possible to load classes that are `controls` and `config` in index.php file without including any file in above of `index.php` file

I mean autoload automatically understands which file is requesting a class or function and include that file for it.

updated code :

```
function __autoload($class_name)
{
    //class directories
    $directorys = array(
        '/Controls/',
        '/Config/',
        '/Utility/'
    );
    //for each directory

    $ds = "/"; //Directory Seperator
    $dir = dirname(__DIR__); //Get Current file path
    $windir = "\\"; //Windows Directory Seperator
    $path = str_replace($windir, $ds, $dir);

    foreach($directorys as $directory)
    {
        //see if the file exsists
        if(file_exists( $path . $directory . $class_name . '.php'))
        {
            require_once( $path . $directory . $class_name . '.php');
            //only require the class once, so quit after to save effort (if you got more, then name them something else
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I have updated the code and it include files, but the only problem that i have is that this function is not running automatically,

for example my autoload file is in : `root/Controls/autoload.php`
and I need some classes and functions in :`root/portal/index.php`

when i define classes in index.php i get error that the file is not exists
and i should manually call `autoload.php` file in `index.php`

how can i make autoload smart which i shouldn't have include it in each file for including classes ?

please help me out.
thanks in advance

Comment: use `set_include_path`

Comment: hi @anonymous in which file should i use set_include_path exactly ?

Comment: create an autoload file in `Controls` like this `$directorys = array('./Controls/','./Config/','./Utility/', get_include_path()); set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,$directorys));`

Comment: I updated the code above is it right ? i'm getting error in index.php file in portal/main/index.php file though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple manual solution : put your `autoload` file in your project root and include it in your index file this will do the job.

but if you want to use `htaccess` or `php.ini` :
Place a file called `.user.ini` into the document root and add the [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) directive in there:

```
auto_prepend_file = /home/user/domain.com/init.php
```

The file must be inside PHP's include_path. So you must either set the file's directory to be in the include_path inside php.ini, or do it in the .htaccess with a php_value statement.

```
php_value include_path ".:/path/to/file_directory"
php_value auto_prepend_file "file.php
```

If you use the above method in .htaccess, be sure to copy the include_path from php.ini in and add the :`/path_to/file_directory` so you don't lose any already needed includes.

Alternatively, just add :`/path/to/file_directory to include_path directly in the php.ini`

**Update**

If you cannot modify the include_path, you might try specifying a relative path to the auto_prepend_file. This should work since the file path sent is processed identically as if it was called with require():

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "./file.php"
```

Comment: your simple solution worked but in every sub directory it needs to re include the autoload file

Comment: @anonymox depends how did you structured/organized your code. If you took down the path of standard OOP and todays wab apps and/or frameworks out there you wouldn't need to re-include the autoload file all over the place.
You would simply have a single PHP e.g. index.php "bootstrap" file through which all requests would flow, and only in that file you would need to include/require the autoload file.
But if you are in your app accessing php files directly via URL e.g. than sure you would need to explicitly re-include autoload in such files.

Comment: @IvanVeštić I created a index bootstrap but i think it's not what it should be, It includes autoload file in all first layer files and folders but when i go to subfolders and files for example : control/modules/text.php i have to require that autoload to make it work.

Comment: should i create a dynamic path loader for all request? then send them to the autoload ?

Answer (score 6):

1. Your program is only as smart as you.
   If you dream of solving a problem beyond a mainstream language's capability, problem is with your dream, not the language.
2. To autoload PHP code, set [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) in php.ini to your autoloader script.
   Alternatively you may make it the centralised entry point and direct traffic with [mod_rewirte](https://www.webmasterworld.com/php/4578018.htm).

> This is bad practice.  Both methods relies on server config such as .htaccess, and is not always available.
>   You may also override existing configs or fail to rewrite some paths.
>
> You should manually centralise the PHP requests (and seal off non-entry points), or require_once in each entry points.

3. PHP [does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737199/autoloader-for-functions) support autoloading function.
   Include all functions you might need if you can't bother to code their inclusions.

> Look at Wikipedia, Magento, or WordPress.
>   They have hundreds if not thousands global functions.
>
> Do not worry about *including* - trust your disk cache and enable [opcode cache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php).
>   Static inclusion is [pretty fast](http://seeit.org/2010/06/11/php-the-include-include_once-performance-debate/) and with opcode cache it may be faster than conditional loads.

4. If you have multiple classes / functions in a file, I know of no dynamic language that can magically pick the correct file to include.
   Your autoloader looks pretty [standard](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

> You can dynamically define anything in PHP.
>   PHP can never be confident what it will get unless it really runs the code.
>   Auto loaders are simply trusting filenames as correct and complete declaration of what is in the file.
>
> Since your autoloader scans all folders, you may want to make a static file map on first run, and use the map for subsequence loads.
>   Assuming you are not going to create class files dynamically with PHP, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the full explained answer, but according to your answer part 3 manually including files are ok and fast ? not doubt about speed but it's a wast of time to write every inclusion !!! what about symphony and codeigniter frameworks? they're also using autoloaders. and i'm creating my own framework which i want to use autoloader.

Comment: the idea of using autoloader is to code and use classes anywhere in the project without bothering to include needed files or classes

Comment: @anonymox Note that I said include the *functions*, not *classes*. Even the software I mentioned put most features in class. I assumed that your autoloader is auto loading single class files fine, once the loader itself is loaded.

Comment: yes it works fine when i manually call it, i'm a bit confuse here : if i load autoload file at the begining of my code for example if i include it in my index.php file the very first index  file would it load all classes and etc for the rest of the files and pages ? instead of including it in php.ini

Comment: @anonymox Unless your "other files and pages" are accessed *through* index.php, they won't have the loader in index.php.  This is why most PHP programs is designed to force all requests to go through index.php - the "centralised entry point" I mentioned.  This is like a house with one main door verses a house with exterior doors in every room. The later is a management / reconstruction nightmare.

Comment: so what's your solution/suggestion ?

Comment: "You should (rewrite the app to) manually centralise the PHP requests, or require_once in each entry points." - in the worse case "entry points" mean all non-auto loaded PHP file. In such a worse case, modify php.ini or mod_rewrite - the linked article has detailed code example - may be more reliable.