# psr-4 how to load files without class / namespace

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

I have a bunch of php files

each file contains one function

no class

no namespace

just global functions.

How can I load those files easily with composer? with psr-4 autoloader or any similar option so I don't have to `require()` all the time all files

Comment: Auto-loading is for classes, not global functions. There are some good suggestions in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737199/autoloader-for-functions especially the one from user _ivoba_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer has support for autoloading functions. The only caveat is the functions are always included, they aren't loaded on demand.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["src/MyLibrary/functions.php", "foo/bar/baz.php"]
    }
}
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files