# Use namespace functions inside of other php page

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm working on a web app and learning more and more about php routing, server management etc. I'm good at front-end, but am a beginner in php developing. I'm learning more about using namespaces and composer etc.

I'm having a really weird issue. My folder structure looks like this:

```
root
  httpdocs
    index.php
    utils
      get-all-languages.php
      data-file-handler.php
      url-helpers.php
    builder
      content
        content.php
  vendor
  config
    config.php
```

I'm using namespace inside of the utils folder.

This is my url-helpers.php:

```
namespace App\Utils\Url;

function getRequestParam($param)
{
    // Retrieve the value of a specific parameter from the $_GET array
    return isset($_GET[$param]) ? $_GET[$param] : '';
}

function getCurrentUrl()
{
    // Get the current URL with the correct protocol and host
    $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
    $url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    return $url;
}

function getCurrentLanguage($currentUrl, $redirect = false)
{
    $queryParams = getRequestQueryParams($currentUrl);
    $language = getRequestParam('language', '', $queryParams);
    $languages = \App\Utils\Languages\getAllLanguages();

    if (empty($language) || !in_array($language, $languages)) {
        if ($redirect) {
            $firstLanguage = $languages[0];
            $fallbackUrl = addOrUpdateQueryParam($currentUrl, 'language', $firstLanguage);
            header('Location: ' . $fallbackUrl);
            exit();
        };
    }

    return $language;
}
```

It uses the get-all-languages.php file by the namespace App\Utils\Languages:

```
namespace App\Utils\Languages;

require_once(UTILS_DIR . 'data-file-handler.php');

function getAllLanguages()
{
    // Retrieve all languages from the 'languages.json' file
    $languagesData = \App\Utils\DataFileHandler\readDataFromFile(LANGUAGES_DIR . 'languages.json');

    // Sort the languages based on the 'order' key
    uasort($languagesData, function ($a, $b) {
        return $a['order'] <=> $b['order'];
    });

    // Get the sorted language keys
    $sortedLanguages = array_keys($languagesData);

    // Return the sorted languages
    return $sortedLanguages;
}
```

These two pages work fine, when I remove \App\Utils\DataFileHandler\readDataFromFile from the get-all-languages.php.

My data-file-handler.php looks like this:

```
namespace App\Utils\DataFileHandler;

function readDataFromFile($filePath)
{
    if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
        // Throw an exception if the file doesn't exist
        throw new Exception('File not found: ' . $filePath);
    }

    // Read and parse JSON data from a file
    $json = file_get_contents($filePath);
    return json_decode($json, true);
}

function saveDataToFile($filePath, $data)
{
    // Convert data to JSON format
    $json = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    // Write JSON data to a file
    file_put_contents($filePath, $json);
}
```

When trying to open my page, I get this error in the error logs:

> AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call
> to undefined function App\Utils\DataFileHandler\readDataFromFile()
> in
> /var/www/vhosts/feeds.mailmeisters.nl/httpdocs/utils/get-all-languages.php:10\nStack
> trace:\n#0
> /var/www/vhosts/feeds.mailmeisters.nl/httpdocs/utils/url-helpers.php(23):
> App\Utils\Languages\getAllLanguages()\n#1
> /var/www/vhosts/feeds.mailmeisters.nl/httpdocs/app/builder/content/content.php(12):
> App\Utils\Url\getCurrentLanguage()\n#2
> /var/www/vhosts/feeds.mailmeisters.nl/httpdocs/index.php(56):
> require_once('...')\n#3 {main}\n thrown in
> /var/www/vhosts/feeds.mailmeisters.nl/httpdocs/utils/get-all-languages.php
> on line 10'

It can't find the function `App\\Utils\\DataFileHandler\\readDataFromFile() in /var/www/vhosts/feeds.mailmeisters.nl/httpdocs/utils/get-all-languages.php:10`

But I do not see what I'm doing wrong.

My composer.json is fine as well I think:

```
{
    "require": {
        "twig/twig": "^3.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "httpdocs/"
      }
    } 
}
```

Because the exact same setup works fine for my url-helpers.php. I don't get the error message that it can't find the function getAllLanguages();.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here and why my get-all-languages.php can't find the data-file-handler.php functions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your `UTILS_DIR` constant is probably wrong. If it contains a relative path, this path is resolved at runtime from the location of the file that is **using** it and not the file that is **defining** it.

To prevent that, you may either :

- Use an absolute path
- Start your path with the magic constant `__DIR__` which will effectively transform your relative path in an absolute path at runtime (recommended, because it still works if you move your code elsewhere). See [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php) for more information.

Side note : the PSR-4 autoload you defined in composer.json will autoload classes only, not functions. Unless you have classes elsewhere in your "httpdocs" folder, it does nothing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @halibut. My util DIR is defined in my config.php:
define('HTTPDOCS_DIR', __DIR__ . '/../httpdocs'); // Path to the 'httpdocs' folder
define('UTILS_DIR', HTTPDOCS_DIR . '/utils/'); // Path to the 'utils' folder

The fact that PSR-4 autoload doesn't load functions is news for me. Do you know if there's another way to autoload functions?

Comment: Composer can do that (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17925443/22310127)). But it will not lazy load the files, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Instead, you could create one class per file and define your functions as static methods in these classes. Then you can remove all your `require` instructions. Composer will lazy autoload your classes and methods. All you have to do is make sure that your folders and files names respect the [PSR-4 standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

Eg : Utils/DataFileHandler.php file should contain class DataHandler from namespace App\Utils